# Encoding Problems - PHP, MySQL - Strange Behavior

Tags: php, mysql, json, encoding

I am trying to make an Ajax call and get the response in JSON. The problem is that the JSON gets characters that are not encoded correctly. Therefore, the JSON is not correctly formed and gets and error.

This only happens in my localhost, I have tried it in the server and it works fine. I don't understand what is happening.

Here is the Ajax call:

```
var getEmployees = function () {
    var name;
    var code;
    var nameCode;
    var result = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getEmployees.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var len = data['data'].length;
            for( var i = 0; i<len; i++) {
                name = data['data'][i]['name'];
                code = data['data'][i]['code'];
                nameCode = name + ' - ' + code;
                result.push(nameCode);
            }
            renderEmployees(name);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, textResponse) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(textResponse);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the PHP code for $getEmployees.php

```
-- Validate database

$getEmployeesQuery = "SELECT e.id, e.name, e.code, e.email, e.active, e.updated_at ";
$getEmployeesQuery .= "FROM emp e ";
$getEmployeesQuery .= "LEFT JOIN ecredit ec ON e.id = ec.employee_id ";
$getEmployeesQuery .= "LEFT JOIN credit c ON c.id = ec.credit_id ";
$getEmployeesQuery .= "LEFT JOIN product p ON p.id = c.product_id ";
$getEmployeesQuery .= "WHERE e.company_id = " .$companyId. " ";
if (isset($searchQuery)) {
    $getEmployeesQuery .= "and (e.name LIKE '%".$searchQuery."%' ";
    $getEmployeesQuery .= "or e.code LIKE '%".$searchQuery."%' ";
    $getEmployeesQuery .= "or e.email LIKE '%".$searchQuery."%') ";
}
if (isset($status)) {
    $getEmployeesQuery .= "and e.active = ".$status." ";
}
$getEmployeesQuery .= "group by e.id ";
$getEmployeesQuery .= "order by e.updated_at desc";

$getEmployees = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $getEmployeesQuery);


if ($getEmployees) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getEmployees)) {
        $getEmployeeCreditsQuery = "SELECT sum(ec.quantity) as quantity, c.expiration_date ";
        $getEmployeeCreditsQuery .= "FROM ecredit ec ";
        $getEmployeeCreditsQuery .= "JOIN credit c ON c.id = ec.credit_id ";
        $getEmployeeCreditsQuery .= "WHERE c.expiration_date > '$currentDate' and ec.employee_id = ".$row['id']." ";

        $getEmployeeCredits = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $getEmployeeCreditsQuery);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($getEmployeeCredits)>0) {
            while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($getEmployeeCredits)){
                $quantity = $result['quantity'];
            }
        } else {
            $quantity = 0;
        }

        $getEmployeesInfo['data'][] = array(
            'id' => (int)$row['id'],
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'code' => $row ['code'],
            'email' => $row ['email'],
            'status' => (int)$row['active'],
            'quantity' => $quantity
        );

    }

    foreach ($getEmployeesInfo['data'] as $row => $id) {
        $rowIds['meta']['rowIds'][] = $id['id'];
    }

    $mergedArray = array_merge($rowIds,$getEmployeesInfo);

    return print_r(json_encode($mergedArray));

}
```

Here is an example of the data:
[data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI0uW.png)

When the data is small it works fine but when the JSON passes over 65528 characters, always gets an unidentified character in this position, this is the Ajax response in the console.

```
parsererror
tagify-employees.js:26 SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 65528
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at ajaxConvert (plugins.bundle.js:9013)
    at done (plugins.bundle.js:9483)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (plugins.bundle.js:9785)
```

I have reviewed all the data and it doesn't contain any special characters. Also, the meta and header tags are specified for UTF-8. Here are the configurations for the server.

[Server info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKU83.png)

Please, I don't know why this is happening and I cannot try certain features on my computer. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could guide me. Also if you need more info, I can provide it.

Comment: Why `print_r`??

Comment: I have tried echo and printf but no success as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: No idea, depends what the rest of your code is like. Just seemed odd. Have you tried dumping out the JSON in PHP and checking that it's valid before it gets to the JS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698623/php-json-encode-large-arrays-gets-truncated _might_ be relevant. Unsure.

Comment: Given the complication only occurring locally at a certain file length, do you know if your local environment's php settings (i.e. `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your .ini) are the same as the server you've tested on?

Comment: I stopped reading over the SQL when I saw open SQLi injections: I hope the query returns something (have you checked this?). Ensure that your encoding is the same through-out your application. Ensure you have a `header('Content-Type: application/json')` set in your PHP script.

Comment: 65528 is only slightly less than 2^16.  I wonder if that is a useful clue.

Comment: Can you get a hex dump of the bad character (and a few chars around it)?

Comment: @Jonnix Thanks Jonnix I have tried to print the array before is a json and the same problem.

Comment: @TCooper Thanks, no there are not the same I will adjust that and try again.

Comment: @Jaquarh and Dharman thanks I will fix the SQL injections, you guys are absolutely right. I am still a rockie as you can see but I will fix all the SQL statements to prevent SQL injections.